# How to install Xdebug on PHP 5.6

Tags: php, xdebug

I have httpd 2.4.38 win64 VC11 and old PHP 5.6.4 Win32 VC11 x64. I want to install Xdebug but I have an error:

```
Failed loading C:/laragon/bin/php/php-5.6.0-Win32-VC11-x64/ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64
```

My php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\laragon\bin\php\php-5.6.4-Win32-VC11-x64\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

I don't understand this error, because in my opinion, I have a good version of Apache, PHP, and of course Xdebug. Where is the problem?

Comment: Use another Xdebug build -- you are trying to use NTS build (Non Thread Safe), which is mainly for IIS. If PHP is used as Apache module, it must be Thread Safe one. Check your PHP (check `phpinfo()` output captured via browser) and see if it uses NTS or not.

Comment: please try upgrading to php7.3

Comment: I see that your 'failed loading' line has the part `php-5.6.0` and your php.ini references `php-5.6.4` . That sounds like a difference to me. Unsure how you're loading a different file then you specify but maybe it's the wrong php.ini you're editing?

Answer (score 9):

Yesterday I ran into a problem regarding `xdebug` and this(`5.6`) version of `PHP`.

Originally I had gotten the latest version of `5.6` (`5.6.4`) and didn't realized my `xdebug` was `NTS` while my PHP was `TS`. I got the `NTS` version of PHP instead and it started to work.

So based on your information I would say you need to either get the `TS` version of `xdebug` or else the `NTS` version of `PHP`

https://xdebug.org/download -- `PHP 5.6 VC11 TS`
or
https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/ -- `php-5.6.0-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip`

This post got me there (realizing my NTS/TS difference) -- https://forum.laragon.org/topic/169/solved-xdebug-php-7-0-8/16

I also did notice (as mentioned in another answer) your error and `ini` file do not match:
**Error:**    `C:/laragon/bin/php/php-5.6.0-Win32-VC11-x64/ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64`
**Calling:** `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-5.6.4-Win32-VC11-x64\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64`

`5.6.0 !== 5.6.4`, so that could very well have been your issue (just getting it all synced to `5.6.4`)

Answer (score 2):

Use the wizard at https://xdebug.org/wizard to tell you which binary you need to download. However, PHP 5.6 is no longer supported by the PHP project, so you really need to upgrade to PHP 7.3 as well, where an improved Xdebug and PHP versions should be really helpful.